# Is it possible to decide access level of Jenkins users where the login is through a group in Azure AD using SAML 2.0?

Tags: jenkins, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, role-based-access-control

I have a jenkins instance with

- A group "Jenkins NP" created in Azure with some users (example : A,B,C) added in it
- SAML Single Sign On(SSO) plugin installed and SAML 2.0 selected as the security realm
- Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin installed and being used to add the users/groups
- In the Global role "Jenkins NP" has been added and given admin role and so every user inside the group "Jenkins NP" has admin access to the jenkins instance

My question is that....is it possible to give some specific users in the same group different access? If there are 3 users in the group "Jenkins NP" -- A,B,C. I want A to have admin rights and B&C to only have job view/run access.

I'm using Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin which is making every user in "Jenkins NP" an admin by default and cannot be overwritten even if I assign them non-admin roles.
Is there any other plugin I can use or some configuration I am missing in this plugin to do the same?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!